# High input resistance - FET

Tags: mosfet

What does high input resistance in fet mean? I always see this term when dealing with fet transistors like jfet and mosfets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a MOSFET the high input resistance is caused by the isolation layer between gate and channel (blue in the picture):

[image]

The layer is made of SiO\$_2\$, which has an *extremely* high resistance of 10\$^{16}\$ Ω\$\cdot\$m, and is one of the best insulators existing.

That means that the voltage applied to the gate has no way to go, so there won't be any current, apart from a small leakage current (*not* through the SiO\$_2\$). MOSFET input opamps may have input resistances as high as 10\$^{13}\$ Ω.

Answer (score 8):

Resistance determines the amount of current that flows when a certain voltage is applied. High resistace means less current (at the same Voltage). Ohms law, google if you don't understand that yet.

The input resistance is the equivalent resistance of the input (in a FET's case, between the gate and the drain == ground (in most cases)). So it means that to keep a FET on, you have to supply only a very very minimal current.

Contrast this with a normal (bipolar) transistor, which needs a certain current (collector current divided by the transistor's Beta == amplification factor) to be switched 'on'. For a large collector current this base current can be significant, often too much for a microcontroller pin to deliver directly. And because the base-emittor resistance is very low (above the cutoff voltage of ~ 0.6V) you need a resistor to limit the base current. These two factors make it often easier to interface a microcontroller to a suitable FET than to a bipolar transistor.