# Do N-channel MOSFETs require a pull-down resistor?

Tags: power-supply, mosfet

I'm using an N-channel mosfet to supply power to a servo. The problem is that even with the gate set at low, I'm still getting some amount of voltage (~0.9V in a 5V system) coming through. Do I need a pull-down in case the pin is floating?

Here's the current schematic:

[image]

Comment: Why the 250 uF capacitor at that place?

Comment: This drives a servo. The cap is there to minimize servo "chatter"

Comment: Then it is in the wrong place, it should be between vbat and ground.

Comment: Um. It *is* between V_BATT and ground - just through the N-MOSFET.

Comment: Hence when the mosfet is switched on, it has to charge the elco. Bad for the fet, bad for the elco. And when you want tos witch the servo off it will stay powered for some (short? depends on the power it draws) time. Both little problems are eliminated by placing the elco at the power.

Comment: why is that bad for the fet?

Comment: What will be the current?

Comment: up to 250mA @ 5V

Comment: Why would it be limited to that value?

Comment: because you didn't ask the current of what. the current drawn by the servo peaks at about 250. if you're asking about the max current drawn by the charging cap, then i'm not sure as the cap's datasheet doesn't specify an ESR. Now - would you like to answer the original question of "why is that bad for the fet," or do you want to keep playing this game?

Comment: You have answered it for yourself. By placing the elco as you did you get an unknown inrush current every time you switch the FET on (which will degrade the cap's lifetime, or forces you to get one with a high current spec), and as a bonus the servo will work up to an unspecified time after you switched it off.

Comment: i appreciate the advice (and will take it), but the easter egg hunt is unnecessary and condescending. if i had the answers, i wouldn't come to a Q&A site to get them.

Comment: In my second comment I gave the solution. When you asked for the reason I gave it in my next comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, if you just tristate after pulling it high, then the gate will stay floating high. You either need a resistor to pull it down to ground or you need the input signal to drive it low.

The resistor can/should be relatively high valued compared to your input resistor to prevent excessive voltage drop when you have it set as a high input. You only have to drain the inherent capacitance on the MOSFET gate when you're pulling it low so even at a high resistance to ground the RC time constant is usually relatively short.

Comment: Is the input resistor really needed? Doesn't the MOSFET have an extremely high input impedance itself? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/42316/32616

Comment: I just read about the input capacity which makes my question obsolete.